# Sorting a LinkedHashSet

Tags: java, sorting, linkedhashset

I'm wondering if it's possible to sort a `LinkedHashSet`. I've tried the statement

```java
Collections.sort((List<Comparable> paragraph);
```

However, that just throws an error that it cannot be casted into a `List`. Is there a way of doing this, or should I use another data structure?

Comment: Use a `TreeSet` instead.

Comment: You could use SortedSet

Comment: use a sortedSet instead, cause `set` in a mathematical view has no order

Comment: @TaW I deleted it because it was a simple mistake on my part, I was storing the year and rating as String instead of Integers and was forgetting to parse them. That is why they showed misordered on the chart.

Comment: Indeed, which is what I wrote in my comment and my answer.. And I find the resulting misordering quite instructive.. Oh well.

Comment: My apologizes for that

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You should use a `SortedSet` such as [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) or [`ConcurrentSkipListSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html) if you care about ordering based on comparison (e.g., sorted order).

A `LinkedHashSet` preserves order based on *insertion order*.

If you really want to use `Collections.sort` you can convert the LHS into a List by actually constructing a `List` (though the question doesn't tell us the type of `paragraph` so I'll assume it is `String`)

```
List<String> listParagraph = new ArrayList<String>(paragraph);
Collections.sort(listParagraph)
```

but that's probably not the best approach.

Answer (score 3):

[Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) does not work on `Set`s, only on `List`s. If you need to sort the data that is already in a `Set`, you might want to first add them into a `List`.

Answer (score 2):

You can add LinkedHashSet object (linkedHashSet) to TreeSet and it will be sorted.

```
TreeSet<T> treeSet = new TreeSet<t>();
treeSet.addAll(linkedHashSet);
```

treeSet is the sorted set.

Note that you need to make these T type comparable(by implementing Comparator interface).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can. Java 8 has made our life easier :)

creating a linked list (it looks simple to me, you can directly insert in LinkedHashSet)

```
LinkedList<String> lList = new LinkedList<String>();
lList.add("Ravi");
lList.add("Vijay");
lList.add("Ravi");
lList.add("Ajay");
lList.add(null);

LinkedHashSet<String> lHashSet = new LinkedHashSet<>();
lHashSet.addAll(lList);
```

let's sort now

```
lHashSet.stream().sorted((String s1,String s2)->{       
    return s1.compareTo(s2);
});

//now print it
System.out.println("----");
lHashSet.forEach(action->{
   System.out.println(action);
});
System.out.println("----");
```

Output-

```
----
Ravi
Vijay
Ajay
null
----
```

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you really need to sort an existing `LinkedHashSet` and can't create a new sorted one, you could create a sorted copy of the data, clear the original set, then add all the elements.

```java
TreeSet<String> sortedCopy = new TreeSet<>(linkedHashSet);
linkedHashSet.clear();
linkedHashSet.addAll(sortedCopy);
```