# Sort List based on index value

Tags: java, sorting, hashset, linkedhashset

This is what i have so far, i'm trying to sort a bunch of **`List<String>`'s** based on the value of an index.

```
LinkedHashSet<List<String>> sorted = new LinkedHashSet<List<String>>();
```

How do i sort the LinkedHashSet in order from **Highest to Lowest index 2 value** of the List's?

Example input:

```
List<String> data1 = Database.getData(uuid);
double price = Double.valueOf(data1.get(2))

data1.add("testval");
data1.add("testval");
data1.add("100.00");

sorted.add(data1);
```

and on another seperate List:

```
List<String> data2 = Database.getData(uuid);
double price = Double.valueOf(data2.get(2))

data2.add("anotherval");
data2.add("anotherval");
data2.add("50.00");

sorted.add(data2);
```

Output of the **sorted LinkedHashSet** in descending order.

```
testval testval 100.00
anotherval anotherval 50.00
```

Sorry if this is confusing, im not sure where to go about sorting like this.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17370909/sorting-a-linkedhashset

Comment: Is the value always the 3rd element in the list?

Comment: Yeah value is same index always

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new class to represent you complex objects. There is no need to store multiple values in a list when you can do it in objects.

```
public class ComplexObject {
    private String description1;
    private String description2;
    private Double value;

    public ComplexObject(String description1, String description2, Double value) {
        this.description1 = description1;
        this.description2 = description2;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void setDescription1(String description1) {
        this.description1 = description1;
    }

    public String getDescription1() {
        return description1;
    }

    public void setDescription2(String description2) {
        this.description2 = description2;
    }

    public String getDescription2() {
        return description2;
    }

    public void setValue(Double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Double getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Then add elements to the list and sort it using a new, custom, comparator:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<ComplexObject> complexObjectList = new ArrayList<ComplexObject>();

    //add elements to the list
    complexObjectList.add(new ComplexObject("testval","testval",100.00d));
    complexObjectList.add(new ComplexObject("anotherval","anotherval",50.00d));

    //sort the list in descending order based on the value attribute of complexObject
    Collections.sort(complexObjectList, new Comparator<ComplexObject>() {
            public int compare(ComplexObject obj1, ComplexObject obj2) {
                return obj2.getValue().compareTo(obj1.getValue()); //compares 2 Double values, -1 if less , 0 if equal, 1 if greater
            }
        });

    //print objects from sorted list
    for(ComplexObject co : complexObjectList){
        System.out.println(co.getDescription1()+" "+co.getDescription2()+" "+co.getValue());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
testval testval 100.0
anotherval anotherval 50.0
```

Comment: This works, however only once i reversed the order.
Collections.reverse(complexObjectList);

Comment: That's the idea, just a note on your code: If your getters and setters are used just to get a references and pass the values to set, don't you think it would be simplier to make the attributes public and avoid the boilerplate code?

Comment: @PabloFranciscoPérezHidalgo I'd argue that the ComplexObject should be immutable, remove the setters. Otherwise you risk changing objects after sorting. I'd rather see a constructor with private fields and just the getters. I don't think getters/setters are boilerplate, they are easily generated by an IDE and add something useful to the mix.

Comment: @RoyvanRijn It was just a generic example, of course we don't need the setters here. They were automatically generated by the IDE. And I never use public for attributes, call me anal about it.

Comment: @RoyvanRijn You are right, that is safer. I wanted to remark that having direct access using getters/setters seems somehow useless.

Comment: @ThatGuy343 just change obj1.getValue().compareTo(obj2.getValue()) to obj2.getValue().compareTo(obj1.getValue(), edited the code to reflect this.

Answer (score 3):

First, and extracted from [Oracle's Java reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html):

> This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is the order in which elements were inserted into the set

So you can't sort your data just inserting it into the `LinkedHashSet`.
You may be confusing that set implementation with [SortedSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html). `SortedSet` allows you to pass a comparator which will determine the elements order in the data structure.

On the other hand, I don't know whether you chose you `List<String>` arbitrarily but it seems to me a wiser option to aggregate your the 3 strings as a class attributes. The point is that, if your elements are always going to be 3 elements, being the last one a double value: Why do you need a dynamic structure as a `List`?

**EDIT**

Here you have a possible better implementation of what you want:

```
public class Element
{
    public Element(String a, String b, double val) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.val = val;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return a + "\t" + b + "\t" + val;
    }

    public String a;
    public String b;
    public double val;
}
```

And you can use this class to store your elements. An example of use:

```
 SortedSet<Element> sorted = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<Element>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Element o1, Element o2) {
            return (new Double(o1.val)).compareTo(o2.val);
        }
    });

sorted.add(new Element("testval", "testval", 100.0));
sorted.add(new Element("anotherval", "anotherval", 50.0));
for(Element el: sorted)
{
    System.out.println(el);
}
```

Note that the comparator is given as an instance of an anonympous inner class implementing Java's `Comparator` interface.

Comment: Can you provide an example of passing a comparator with this scenario?

Comment: As commented above, I'm not a fan of having those public fields. You risk some other code coming/having a reference to the fields and changing the values after sorting. IMHO it is better to have private fields and getters making it immutable.

Comment: @RoyvanRijn I am a supporter of immutability, my point in this example is to keep things simple. The OP initial code was using lists to store a structure...

Comment: @ThatGuy343 Haha No worries, mark the one which helped you more, that's the aim of the site ;)

Answer (score 3):

- Firstly, you shouldn't use a `LinkedHashSet` but a `TreeSet`. `LinkedHashSet` will retain the insertion order without sorting.
- Secondly, you need to initialize your `TreeSet` with a `Comparator` that compares based on whichever value of your `List` is required, that is, **if** you know the index of the `String` that will represent a `double` value in advance. Otherwise I would recommend using custom objects instead of `List`.

If you decide to use custom objects, you don't necessarily need to initialize your `TreeSet` with a `Comparator` as second argument.

Instead, you could have your custom objects implement `Comparable`, and implement a one-time comparation logic there.

It all depends on whether you only need to sort in a particular order.

Finally, custom objects will require you to override `equals` and `hashCode`.

Comment: Seems to me that i should be using objects.

Comment: @ThatGuy343 not `Object`s, mind you. Custom objects. Something like `MyTransferObject`, with getters/setters for relevant fields.