# Adding data into a list and keeping the right order

Tags: java

Consider the following piece of code in `Java`:

```
final LinkedHashSet<String> alldata = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
for (final String folder: folders) {
    for (final String d: data.get(folder)) {
        allData.add(d);
    }
}
```

when `folders` is `List<String>` and `data` is `Map<String, List<String>>`.

Example of `data`:

```
{data1=[prepare, echo2, echo1], data2=[prepare, sleep2, check]}
```

Until now, I didn't care about the order of the `allData` and it would look:

```
[prepare, echo1, echo2, sleep2, check]
```

I have a list `dataList` which contains the right order of the data (and of course all data):

```
[prepare, sleep1, echo1, sleep2, echo2, check]
```

I want to iterate through the `data` and add into the `allData` those that are defined in `data` in the right order.

The output for the previous example should be:

```
[prepare, echo1, sleep2, echo2, check]
```

Another example:

```
data = {data1=[prepare], data2=[prepare, sleep2,sleep1,echo2]}
dataList = [prepare, sleep1, echo1, sleep2, echo2, check]
```

expected output:

```
allData = [prepare,sleep1,sleep2,echo2]
```

Of course, there could be more than two inner data (`data1,data2,...,dataN`).
I'm not sure that its the right thing to add code into the inner `for` loop, because by doing I'll have to add another loop to iterate through the `dataList`, and it does not feel efficient (3 loops).

What good, clean and efficient way should I use?

**EDIT**: I don't try to sort the collection. But I thought of doing the following algorithm:

Creating a `Set` of all data and then iterate through the `dataList` and insert into the `LinkedHashSet`.

Is it efficient?

**EDIT2**: What I tried to do:

```
final Set<String> activeData = new HashSet<String>();
for (final String folder: folders) {
    for (final String d: fubsAndSteps.get(folder)) {
        activeData.add(d);
    }
}

final LinkedHashSet<String> allData = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
for (final String main_data : dataList) {
    for (final String active_data: activeData) {
        if (main_data.equals(active_data)) {
            allData.add(active_data);
        }
    }
}
```

That works for me, but it does not look really good, I mean 4 `for` loops. It does not feel clean and efficient. Is there a better algorithm?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting a LinkedHashSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17370909/sorting-a-linkedhashset)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the solution is 
Iterate over `datalist` and check the element exists in `data`, then add it to `allData` which keeps order

```
    Set<String> tempSet = new HashSet<>();
    folders.forEach(folder -> tempSet.addAll(data.get(folder))); // flattening all the data elements into single set

    //Iterate over dataList where you are already maintaining order. If element exists, add it to allData
    dataList.forEach(item -> {
        if(tempSet.contains(item)){
            allData.add(item);
        }
    });
```

If you are using Java 7 or below

```
    Set<String> tempSet = new HashSet<>();
    // flattening all the data elements into single set
    for(String folder:folders) {
        tempSet.addAll(data.get(folder));
    }

    //Iterate over dataList where you are already maintaining order. If element exists, add it to allData
    for(String item:dataList){
        if(tempSet.contains(item)){
            allData.add(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: forEach loop is available for java 8 and above

Comment: @TTaJTa4 I missed it while converting the code from forEach loop to for loop :-)